# how to validate and return data if we have stored data in .txt file?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a notepad (.txt) file which has three fields viz ID Name and Location. I want to read this data in C# using streamreader and check for the condition whether ID is there or not in a file. If yes i should get that row as output else error.

suppose i have following txt file with fields as

```
00125  JAMES  LONDON
00127  STARK  USA
00128  ARNOLD AUSTRALIA
```

NOW, i should ask the user to enter there ID. If Id matches then i should get that particular row as output. E.g. if user enters 00127 then i should get output as

```
00127 JAMES LONDON
```

I know this would have been very simple had the data was stored in database. But what if data is stored in .txt file.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried? Have you researched this for yourself? http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Is everything really in one line or are ID Name and Location in one line then the next ID Name and Location in the next line? In any case, `String.Split(' ')` comes to mind...

Comment: This may be relevant - http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution (assume you have fixed format of ID - five digits):

```
var users = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt")
                .ToDictionary(line => line.Substring(0, 5));
```

That creates dictionary with lines as values and ids as keys. Usage:

```
string line = users["00125"]; // 00125  JAMES  LONDON
```

---

That was simplest solution. But actually, I'd introduce some class like:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public static User Parse(string s)
    {
        var parts = s.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return new User {
            Id = Int32.Parse(parts[0]),
            Name = parts[1],
            Location = parts[2]
        };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0:00000} {1} {2}", Id, Name, Location);
    }
}
```

Then parse each line and put users to dictionary of type `Dictionary<int, User>`. That will make your code strongly typed and easier to maintain:

```
var users = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt")
                .Select(line => User.Parse(line))
                .ToDictionary(u => u.Id);

var user = users[127];
string name = user.Name; // STARK
Console.WriteLine(user); // 00127 STARK USA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `StreamReader` to read the contents from a file.

Then, you can split the `String` using `Split`.

With that, you'd be able to add all the items in a two dimensional array. Then the array would look like `{{00125, JAMES, LONDON}, {00127, STARK, USA}, {00128, ARNOLD, AUSTRALIA}}`. Using that, you can compare the input to the first entry of every array, and return the data accordingly.

That should give you a clear view on which way to go from now.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

- Read the bloody file every time you get a request. This will work fine if the file is small and requests aren't frequent. You read line by line, and compare `id` to the user's `id`. Really fast to implement, but dead dumb in resource utilization. Run time complexity is O(N) - you need to scan the whole file in worst case.
- You can modify first option and add a layer of caching. If you get frequent queries for the same `id`, you will get a nice performance boost. Run time complexity is still O(N) - you need to scan the whole file in worst case. And this is still far away from being fast.
- You can also try and sort the file `ids` once. With best algorithms this will take `O(N x Log(N)` time, the time you spend *once* preprocessing the data. However, any read query could be executed in `O(Log(N))` using binary search based on `id`.

If you are looking for code snippets, I would search for `StreamReader`, `TextReader`, `StreamWriter`, `binary search`, `quick sort`. There are plenty samples in the wild...